# Generic Vector in Java

Tags: java, arrays, generics

Why doesn't the add() method here compile?

```
Vector<?> vectorList[] = new Vector<?>[10];
vectorList[0].add("elem1");
```

Thanks

Comment: In these cases it's usually best to post the compiler error. Since you haven't you posted the Java boiler plate, we can't guarantee what the exact error is.

Answer (score 3):

There are several problems with your code. Firstly, the elements of the array are uninitialized, and so you are adding to a non-existent vector. And, secondly, adding to a generic container where the type is a wildcard doesn't make sense, because it could be restricted to a more limited type, and so adding would not be safe.

You can fix the first problem, by filling your array:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++ ){
    vectorList[i] = new Vector<Integer>(); // can replace Integer with
                                           // any binding for ? 
}
```

Now that you've seen that it can be filled with vectors that do not accept type String, you can see why the add statement would subsequently fail. You can fix that by binding to a specific type (e.g. String) earlier.

See [Java Generics: Wildcards](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/extra/generics/wildcards.html) from the Java tutorial for more information.

**EDIT**
It seems I am doubted, and so I have the following complete, compilable example:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Vector<?> vectorList[] = new Vector<?>[10];
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++ ){
            vectorList[i] = new Vector<Integer>();
        }
        System.out.println("Hello world");
    }
}
```

Compiling with `javac Main.java` gives no compilation errors.

Comment: This does not compile either (Cannot instantiate the type Vector<?>)

Comment: @portoalet, did you use ? or a specific type in your new statement?

Comment: @portoalet, I've tested it, and I don't have any problems.

Comment: @portoalet, well that would explain it, then. You need to bind the wildcard to a particular type when you actually instantiate.

Comment: hm ok, so there is no way to leave it as wildcard and compile

Comment: @portoalet, not without some serious unsafe casting and completely subverting the type system, no.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't compile because `vectorList[0]` is of type `Vector<?>`, and you can't call `add(T)` on a wildcard collection. You can't call `add(T)` because you can't ensure that the element you are adding is of the (unknown) type that `vectorList[0]` contains.

The lesson here is that generic types and arrays do not play well together. That is, you can't make `vectorList` of type `Vector<String>[]` without an unchecked cast, type `Vector[]` will give you a raw type to deal with, and you can't do what you want with a `Vector<?>[]` (the only one that doen't produce a warning). Instead use some `List<Vector<String>>`.

Answer (score 0):

Because you have to instantiate each vector in the array, not just the array itself

```
vectorList[0] = new Vector<?>();
```

Comment: Even though I instantiated the vector, it still wouldn't compile.